# Using data from InnerText

Tags: c#, winforms, coordinates, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

Is there any option of using data - extracted from InnerText - as the pixels 'y' coordinates position?

I managed to get string elements from .xml file - tag "SequenceInfo".

Example of .xml file:

```
<SequenceInfo HasSmoke="" Azimuth="267.2" Inclination="682" Zoom="10329" TowerName="Makoszka" Time="2015-03-18 13:10:22">
  <Horizon>316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,320,320,320,321,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,324,324,324,324,324,324,324,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,324,324,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,323,324,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,324,324,322,322,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320</Horizon>
</SequenceInfo>
```

I get the text content of the specified node as follows:

316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,320,320,320,321,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,324,324,324,324,324,324,324,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,324,324,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,323,324,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,324,324,322,322,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320

Such data are being stored in object 'xtr' (InnerText property).

Can we push this data even further? For example as 'y' coordinates?

Part of my code below:

```
XmlDocument xtr = new XmlDocument();
string fileName = OFD.FileName;
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
string directoryFullPath = fileInfo.DirectoryName;
fileName = Path.Combine(directoryFullPath, "info.xml");
xtr.Load(fileName);
XmlNodeList list = xtr.GetElementsByTagName("SequenceInfo");
```

Comment: The y position of what exactly?

Comment: So how "y" coordinate data look?

Comment: Nobody knows what this sequence of numbers represents. Add the required details.

Comment: @Haytam
I wish that those values represent the Y positions of the pixels (point). 
For example: the first value means Point(0, 316) and so on.

Comment: How your final data look after push that you want to bind to "y" coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if you've actually retrieved the data, and what you want to do with it once you've extracted it...but here's an example that should get you started:

```
        // ... get the data from your XML somehow ...
        string data = "316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,316,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,318,320,320,320,321,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,324,324,324,324,324,324,324,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,324,324,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,322,323,324,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,326,324,324,322,322,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320,320";
        // Convert the Text Data to Points:
        var points = from y in data.Split(",".ToCharArray()) select new Point(0, int.Parse(y));
        // Do something with the Points:
        foreach(Point p in points)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Thank you!
Yesterday, I extracted string data in table, so I did something similar:

`string[] punkty = xtr.InnerText.Split(',');`

Now I'm going to convert all string data to int, and then attribute all of those to Y coordinate. 

Actually, I don't see how I could possibly manage to do that, but  I'm trying.

For now, I'm trying to this way:

``List<Point> punkty1 = new List<Point>();
            for (int i = 0; i < punkty.Length; i++)
            {
                punkty1.Add(new Point { X = i, Y = **Here's the problem**});
            }``

Comment: `Y = **Here's the problem** `  See my example.  You need `int.Parse()` or `int.TryParse()`.

Comment: It works! Thank you!

`List<Point> punkty1 = new List<Point>();
            for (int i = 0; i < punkty.Length; i++)
            {
                punkty1.Add(new Point { X = i, Y = int.Parse(punkty[i])});
            }`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. 
Here's my code:

```
XmlDocument xtr = new XmlDocument();
            string fileName = OFD.FileName;
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
            string directoryFullPath = fileInfo.DirectoryName;
            fileName = Path.Combine(directoryFullPath, "info.xml");
            xtr.Load(fileName);
            XmlNodeList list = xtr.GetElementsByTagName("SequenceInfo");
            string[] punkty = xtr.InnerText.Split(',');
            List<Point> punkty1 = new List<Point>();
            for (int i = 0; i < punkty.Length; i++)
            {
                punkty1.Add(new Point { X = i, Y = int.Parse(punkty[i])});
            }
```